# Jack London's list —X, Y, and a Z and a J

Tags: punctuation, lists, dashes, colons

> On the sled, securely lashed, was a long and narrow oblong box.  There
>   were other things on the sled—blankets, an axe, *and a* coffee-pot *and*
>   frying-pan; but prominent, occupying most of the space, was the long
>   and narrow oblong box.

The only reason I can discern for using an em-dash is that it's described as being "less formal than a colon."

But what about the list—why does Mr. London suddenly insert *and a... and...* ?

I'm curious because he must've consciously chosen not to write the sentence as follows:

> ...were other things on the sled: blankets, an axe, a coffee-pot
>   and frying-pan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of a colon here would change the emphasis, as the [em dash](http://grammarist.com/grammar/emdash/) is being used to set off a parenthetical statement. He could also have written it like so:

> On the sled, securely lashed, was a long and narrow oblong box. There were other things on the sled (blankets, an axe, and a coffee-pot and frying-pan), but prominent, occupying most of the space, was the long and narrow oblong box.

Using a colon puts the emphasis on the list of "other things", while using the em dash or parenthesis makes this list an aside.

As for the "and a coffee-pot and frying-pan", as Ian mentioned, it's grouping the two items together. The implication is that those two items are a logical unit. You could, for example, say the following instead:

> There were other things on the sled---blankets, an axe, and cooking implements

A similar example:

> She put all the necessities in a bag: deodorant, soap, and a toothbrush and toothpaste.

Answer (score 1):

He intended to group the coffee pot and frying pan together for the reader. Presumably, he did this because they are both cooking vessels.

Answer (score 0):

A semicolon where the em-dash is would not be proper.  A semicolon sits between two complete sentences that make more sense together.  That list by itself is not a complete sentence, and therefore must be attached to a complete sentence.  A semicolon does not attach, but merely associates.
Also, an incomplete-sentence clause separated from a complete sentence clause — such as this one — indicates that the whole sentence or even paragraph could be read without it; it is much like parenthesis, but not quite as removed from the flow.

And as the others have said, the coffee pot and frying pan are more similar than the pan and the axe, the pot and the blanket, or the axe and the blanket, etc.  Therefore, they are grouped together.